# Double slash after 'asset' when deploying war

Tags: tomcat, grails

I got an issue with grails (2.5.3) when deploying or running war ( on tomcat7 )
Disclaimer: I'm new to grail and the project I'm currently working on .
So:

- when using run-app to run my grail application, everything goes just fine
- when using war, or even tomcat deploy and run the generated war on a standalone tomcat7, I can't get the assets to display (no css, script.. well, everything in asset/). Using firefox debug console, I see a "//" after the assets in each failed call to the  resource, like

  http://host:port/context/assets//css/mycss.css

Please note, I don't think it is related to the standalone tomcat, as a run-war gives the same result. The application is deployed on / and the war is named with the appName, so the application url is localhost:port/$appName , I am using a specific target env (using -Dgrails.env=...) but same issue using default

I tried to play a bit with the context path and the war name, but nothing. Any hint ?

Also, (not entirely) unrelated: do you know exactly what "grails war" does ? When I use it, it takes lot of time and resources for a simple packaging. I had to change $GRAILS_OPTSin the startGrails.sh to up the memory size. That seems a bit strange to me for something doing only packaging (I come from java, so I'm used to mvn and assembly)

Thanks.

edit: Obviously, first think I checked, it the presence of // in any property, but nothing

UPDATE :

ok, I think I got it : I read some doc on the asset pipeline plugin, and I understand that using the `<asset>` tag, you have to use a relative path to the assets/ directory. In the project, every time the asset tag is used, the path set in the src property is always begining by a / , like in :

```
<asset:javascript type="text/javascript" src="/js/functions.js" />
```

Anything to do, short of fixing every occurrences of the `<asset>` ? Can I override the default asset directory path from "assets/" to "assets" ?

Comment: What happens when you run: `grails prod run-app`

Comment: whats the value for "grails.app.context " in Config.groovy

Comment: grails.app.context was not set. Setting a value changes nothing. prod run-app works fine. I editied the question, I made a small mistake ( it was from memory yesterday evening, it is actually a // after asset, as in /context/asset//something/somethingelse.css )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so as I thought, the  tags were not well defined. I removed every leading / in the src property.

thks